# Cannot read property 'history' of undefined - React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm trying to link from my SignIn component to my ForgotPassword component.

This is the basic design of my SignIn:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { NativeRouter, withRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-native'
import ForgotPassword from './ForgotPassword'

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

class SignIn extends Component {

    render() {

        return(

                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={value => this.onChangeText('username', value)}
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder='username'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={value => this.onChangeText('password', value)}
                        style={styles.input}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        placeholder='password'
                    />
                    <Button style={styles.button} title="Sign In" onPress={this.signIn.bind(this)} />
                    <TextInput
                        onChangeText={value => this.onChangeText('confirmationCode', value)}
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder='Confirmation Code'
                    />
                    <Button style={styles.button} title="Confirm Sign In" onPress={this.confirmSignIn.bind(this)} />

                    <Link to="/forgotPassword"><Text>Forgot password</Text></Link>


                </View>


        )
    }
}

export default SignIn
```

I have all of my routes for my react router configured in my Routes.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { NativeRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-native'
import ForgotPassword from './ForgotPassword'
import SignIn from './SignIn'
import MainPage from './MainPage'


export default class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NativeRouter>
        <View >
          <Switch>
            <Route  exact path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
            <Route  exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
          </Switch>
        </View>
      </NativeRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

I then import my Routes.js component into my App.js component:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {

    if(this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log('auth:', Auth)
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <View style={{position: 'relative'}}>
              <Search logOut={this.logOut} />
              <LeagueSelect />
              <Card />
          </View>
        </Provider>
      )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Tabs
            screenProps={{
              authenticate: this.authenticate.bind(this)
            }}
          />
          <Routes />
        </View>
    )
  }
}


})
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I've been stuck on this all day.

The end goal is to be able to link from SignIn to ForgotPassword and not leave the SignIn component on the page and only have the ForgotPassword component present.

Comment: Can you pls include the part in which you get that error?

Comment: I get it in my SignIn component.